# Rubygems install or downgrade/remove rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rhel7

I had installed ruby 1.8.7 in a RHEL7 machine, with rubygems 2.7.6. I know 1.8.7 is old, but I need it to run our specific software package. When I tried to install any gem, it runs into a Gem::Package::PathError.

```
$ gem install rb-readline
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::PathError)
installing into parent path CHANGES of /eog/reference/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5 is not allowed
```

Here is my gem env output

```
    YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /eog/reference/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/nrt/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /eog/reference/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /eog/reference/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/nrt/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /eog/reference/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /eog/reference/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/nrt/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin
     - /eog/reference/bin
     - /eog/reference/scripts
     - /eog/reference/matlab
     - /eog/reference/java
     -
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /opt/ngdc/groovy/bin
     - /opt/ngdc/p7zip/bin
     - /home/nrt/.local/bin
     - /home/nrt/bin
```

I suspected installing psych might solve the problem, but it requires ruby >= 2.2.2.

```
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
        There are no versions of psych (>= 0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
        psych requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2. The current ruby version is 1.8.
```

Since I cannot upgrade ruby beyond 1.8.7 which will cause the software to break. I tried the to downgrade rubygems by following command without success.

```
gem update --system 1.3.7
```

Any ideas that I can fix the gem install problem, or if not, downgrade my rubygems to an older version?

Comment: Came across [this thread](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1448), looks like an ongoing bug in rubygems for older ruby. Any ideas how to uninstall/downgrade rubygems?

Comment: Hey, I don't know about your problem question but I know a gem manager that is good! You can manager gem version by folder, is very helpful with you are working with ruby and ruby on rails. Check out: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html 

- Here is the doc.: https://rvm.io/rubies